# Scheme append function workflow

Tags: scheme

Hello I am looking at the append function

```
(define ( append x y )
  (if (null? x) 
      y)

  (cons (car x) 
        (append (cdr x)
                y))))
```

I understand how the list is generated but when the first list x is empty we directly return y,I don't see how we connect it to the first list "x".Does the process go like this (cons a1(cons a2....(cons an y).. )) and how does the program understand to plug in y at (cons an y),Is it because in the end the expression is (cons an-1 ,append (cdr x) y ) and the result of (append (cdr x ),y) is y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function has an error in it such that is in parsing has one closing parens too much in the end. I thin kit's because you close `if` just after `y`. Because of that it will always do the last expression and it fails when `x` is empty.

The correct append looks like this:

```
(define (append x y)
  (if (null? x) 
      y
      (cons (car x) 
            (append (cdr x)
                    y))))
```

I like to explain recursive functions by simplest to general so we start off with the obvious, the base case:

```
(append '() '(3 4))
```

This will be `#t` for `x` being `null?` and the result is `(3 4)`. Now lets try with a one element list as `x`:

```
(append '(2) '(3 4))
```

This is `#f` for `x` being `null? thus you can substitute it with:

```
(cons (car '(2))
      (append (cdr '(2))
              '(3 4)))
```

We can evaluate the accessors on `'(2)`:

```
(cons 2 (append '() '(3 4))
```

Since we did the base case before we know the answer to the `append` part, which is `'(3 4)` so we end up with:

```
(cons 2 '(3 4)) ; ==> (2 3 4)
```

Lets do a new `x`:

```
(append '(1 2) '(3 4))
```

Here as the previous `x` is not `null?` so you substitute with the alternative again:

```
(cons (car '(1 2))
      (append (cdr '(1 2))
              '(3 4)))
```

As the previous time we can evaluate the accessors:

```
(cons 1
      (append '(2)
              '(3 4)))
```

Notice that again we have familiar arguments to `append` so we could just substitute that with our last result, however I take the step before so you see the pattern you noticed:

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 (append '() '(3 4)))) ; ==>
(cons 1 (cons 2 '(3 4)))              ; ==>
(cons 1 '(2 3 4))                     ; ==>
; ==> (1 2 3 4)
```

So if you have a 12 element `x` it gets 12 cons nested before hitting the base case and then it evaluates the the inner to the outer since list are always created from end to beginning since the functions need to evaluate their arguments before applying.